# ReferenceError: OFFSET is not defined

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

When running the function:

```
function updateCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetSummary = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  const range = spreadsheetSummary.getDataRange()
  const values = range.getDisplayValues()
  const transposeCheck = values[0].map((_, iCol) => values.map(row => row[iCol]).some(cell => cell))
  var countBoolean = transposeCheck.filter(Boolean).length + 1
  var spreadsheetCommunityGroups = ss.getSheetByName('Community Groups');
  var cellValueCommunityGroups = spreadsheetCommunityGroups.getRange('A12').getValue();
  var summaryCommunityGroups = OFFSET('A2', 0, countBoolean); 
  sreadsheetSummary.getRange(summaryCommunityGroups).setValue(cellValueCommunityGroups);
}
```

I receive the error `ReferenceError: OFFSET is not defined`.

What I want is to place the value of A12 from the `Community Groups` sheet into the cell "1 column to the right of the last cell in row 2" of the `Summary` sheet.

I count the number of occupied columns and 1 and save this as `countBoolean`, and this is what I am using to offset the columns.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - can you help here please kind sir?

Comment: Please describe what your function and more specifically the line including `OFFSET` should do. Also add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: `offset` is a method that accesses or modifies a range. You have described the offset but have not provided the range to which is refers. [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153117/exception-the-parameters-number-dont-match-the-method-signature-for-spreadsh)

Comment: Unfortunately no @Tedinoz, I've updated my question.

Comment: Check the comment under Ruben's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `offset` of Class Range

The following example returns the cell that is one row below and one column to the right, i.e. if the active range is A1 it will return the Range object corresponding to B2

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().offset(1,1)
```

Related

- [Show the content of an edited cell in a message box above](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101026/88163)
- [Use the script to export values with offset by one column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112704/88163)
- [Cannot figure out how to change selected cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/151547/88163)

Comment: In the OP, the _reference cell_ (`A2`) is incorrectly included in the `OFFSET` as an argument. As this answer shows, offset is a method applied to a range. So something like this `spreadsheetSummary.getRange("A2").offset(0,countBoolean).setValue(cellValueCommunityGroups)` would generate the required outcome.